# Can you change a variable outside of a function (assuming this variable may be a constant)?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, security

In other words if a contract looks like this:

```
contract tokenX  {

bool public started = true;

function end()
{
started = false; 
}


}
```

So everyone should be able to call end() but can someone call "started"?
What if the owner of the contract is the contract itself? Can the contract simply call unknown function and trigger "reinitialization" or is this impossible? Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everybody can execute run(), nobody can set started directly. Since started is public, a getter (but no setter) is automatically generated. Reinitialization of the smart contract is not possible, unless you define a specific function for this task.